# Initialization not liking whitespace mode after upgrading to 29.1?

Tags: init-file, osx, error, whitespace-mode

I have the following configuration for whitespace mode in my .emacs file:

```
(require 'whitespace)
(setq whitespace-style '(trailing lines indentation space-before-tab space-after-tab)
      whitespace-line-column 80)

;; width of tab is 4
(setq default-tab-width 4) ;; 8 is way too many

;; To make the Enter key take you to the next line and indent it automatically, you can put
(global-set-key (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent)
```

But after upgrading to 29.1, starting Emacs keeps failing with the error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Loading file /Users/meng/Dropbox/WorkSpace-Dropbox...")
  require(whitespace)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/Users/xxx/.emacs" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 20488
  load-with-code-conversion("/Users/xxx/.emacs" "/Users/meng/.emacs" t t)
  load("~/.emacs" noerror nomessage)
  startup--load-user-init-file(#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x155f476a5fc431>) #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0x1f3c61addc0da035>) t)
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

Idea?